# Azure Database for PostgreSQL server - Permission denied to create a table space

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

**Context**
In our application we have multiple tablespace, basically for allocating different sizes.

We are evaluating to deploy our application in Azure Database for PostgreSQL server.

**Problem**
While trying to create a table space we got the error

```
ERROR: permission denied to create tablespace "tec_large"
HINT: Must be a superuser to create a tablespace
```

On search we got to this [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-create-users#the-server-admin-account) , which basically says

> the server admin account is not part of the azure_superuser role. Since this service is a managed PaaS service, only Microsoft is part of the super user role.

Can someone please give a hint on this. Is this a no solution limitation of the Azure offer. Or Is there any possibility to hack around.

Comment: "In our application we have multiple tablespace, basically for allocating different sizes."  Why is that a useful thing to do?

Comment: The number of tables are pretty high (around 1000) and are pretty diverse (small meta  data tables to pretty large operational data tables). This segregation make better organization possible and better organization helps in better operation and optimization.

Comment: Any hints @jjanes

Comment: I don't use Azure, but I would be astonished if they allow this.  The point of managed service is that they manage it, not you.  Even on your own system, this is unlikely to make sense.  You want it be better organized so that it can be better organized?  Is there any objective basis by which your better organization is actually better?

Comment: I think you should read the comment once more. I said better operation and optimization. Amazon RDS Postgres support the same feature.